# (400) Bad Request on Azure server while communicating with service

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I have a website and service in Azure webrole. The application uses a ServiceCommunicator class to communicate with the Service. The following code is working fine on my local machine..

```
        private string _url;
        public ServiceCommunicator(string url)
        {
            _url = url;
        }
        public object GetDataFromService()
        {
            //create request
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_url);
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.ContentLength = 0;


            //get response
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

But when this is deployed on cloud (it uses Server 2008 R2 Enterprise) the code  throws following exception

```
The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
```

I am unable to understand why is it happening as the code works properly on local machine.

Comment: Turn on logging.  Or, if you can RDP into the instance, consider traditional IIS troubleshooting techniques to find root cause for the error.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433048.aspx

Comment: @RickRainey I am using windows azure diagnostics. The error mentioned above was logged. Also the service is up and running. I am able to access the service running on server from application hosted on my machine and it woks fine and returns the data properly. But when my application hosted on same webrole as that of the service try to access the service it throws the exception

Comment: Ok.  So then, what is the url you're using when you instantiate the ServiceCommunicator class (from the WebRole)?  You should be able to see the request in the IIS logs.  If not there, then the HTTP Error logs may show it.